# Access database error: The module name xxx is misspelled or refers to a module that doesn't exist

Tags: windows, windows-server-2008, microsoft-access, database, microsoft-access-2003

We are using Access database 2003 (I know, too old) with Win server 2008 in my company. We have one .mdb file split into two.

A couple of days ago we had a problem trying to open modules. It all begin with the fact that our users started to get unrecognized function error while the database was running, and an error that read

> The module name xxx is misspelled or refers to a module that doesn't
>   exist

We have tried to use SaveAsText acModule and we created a new database with the hope that if we import all the data from corrupted file into the new it would solve the problem, but nothing works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I was in your case I would create a new database and import all the data into it. Then debug the codes and see if the issue can be reproduced.

Also a /decompile switch can help in the matter. All what you need is a backup, then open notepad and create a one line .bat/.cmd line with the following:

`"C:\Program Files\Microsoft Office\Office\MSACCESS.EXE" "d:\My Documents\access\mayapp.mdb" /decompile`

Also read tech forums and discussions related with your problem. Almost first that I found: https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/71906/ms-access-mdb-ldb-database-corrupted 
Or find another thread with a solution that is right for you.

And if nothing helps, maybe it is time to call in support?

Comment: More detailed reference for de-compiling: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3266542/how-does-one-decompile-and-recompile-a-database-application/3268188#3268188

Answer (score 0):

2003 works well, but there are a few bugs in it which sometimes mess things up beyond repair.  I'm not really sure of the error you suggest, but this might fix it:

First I have found that frequent backups help greatly.  Then when something goes wrong with a form I simply delete it (or rename it to " (bad)") and then recreate it by opening both the current and backup dbf at the same time and then copying (or dragging) the backup form to the new form area.  This makes it so I don't have to recreate the entire .dbf

Before doing this run your backup and make sure it works.  If not, then select an older backup, until you find one that works.

Hope this helps.  Ask me Q if this is unclear.

(I own a newer version of Access, but prefer 2003 because I think it performs better than the newer versions.)