# Access mdb super slow queries

Tags: microsoft-access

I have an access mdb database file with four tables in it.  It's not overly large (46MB).  It has run for the last two years with no isses, generally fast and quick to respond to queries.

I the last few weeks it has started taking 1-2 minutes to return a query made by DAO in Excel.  When I open the database in the Access application (Access 2003) the tables freeze on load and there is a progress bar in the bottom left corner indicating that it is running a query.  Once this finishes the table then loads, I suspect whatever is causing this behaviour is also causing the long query times.

Any ideas?

Comment: It's virtually impossible to come to any conclusions on this because you haven't provided any information on the hardware or software such as the OS, how long it's been installed, what else is running at the time, or any information on the system resources that are being used. In any event, Access 2003 has been EOL since 2014 and it could just be that its age is now catching up to it.

Comment: Citrix Windows 7 environment

Comment: That still isn't providing much. In any event, Windows 7 is also EOL.

Answer (score 0):

Repair & Compact the database

[methods of Repair and Compact for Access](https://superuser.com/a/1451302/1060127)

And if that doesnt fix it, and there is a reasonable amount of of VBA in the front end,
try Decompile and Compile (followed by another Repair & Compact as above)

[use the /decompile flag](https://superuser.com/questions/881406/access-database-error-the-module-name-xxx-is-misspelled-or-refers-to-a-module-t/882415#882415) when opening the database,

Then go into the VBA editor (Ctrl + G is a quick way to get there) and from the menu bar, choose Debug -> Compile.    Then do another Repair & Compact